# Change file_field_tag appearance to button appearance

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, button, filefield

I am working on a Rails project and I want to use file_field_tag but I'd like it looks like a button.

I have this:

[image]

with this code:

```
= file_field_tag 'attachment'
```

I want something like this:

[image]

and I attempted this:

```
= file_field_tag 'attachment', class: 'btn btn-large btn-warning'
```

but I got this:

[image]

How can I change the file_field_tag's appearance in order to achieve it looks like a button?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

HTML:

```
<span class="btn btn-large btn-warning btn-file">
    Choose File
    <%= file_field_tag :attachment %>
</span>
```

CSS:

```
.btn-file {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.btn-file input[type=file] {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    font-size: 100px;
    text-align: right;
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);
    opacity: 0;
    outline: none;
    background: white;
    cursor: inherit;
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: @IvánCortésRomero Glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

the best way to do this is to do a transparent field using css on top of another style button.
Add a div with a id and a div class wrapper on the css add the style for the button and hide the file_field_tag.

```
<div id="id_attachment">
   <div class="hide_attachment">
     <%= file_field_tag 'attachment'%>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

for tailwind users, this worked for me.

```html
<label class="relative flex justify-center w-full px-4 py-2 overflow-hidden text-sm font-medium text-white bg-blue-600 border border-transparent rounded-md shadow-sm focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-indigo-500 focus:ring-offset-2 hover:bg-blue-700">
 Upload logo
 <%= f.file_field :main_image, class:"absolute top-0 right-0 opacity-0 cursor-pointer min-h-full min-w-full" %>
</label>
```