# Improve file_field_tag appearance

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, filefield

Further to the answer provided to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31925833/change-file-field-tag-appearance-to-button-appearance/54187139#54187139) regarding the appearance improvement of the file_field_tag, how can I replace the "Choose file" text with the filename after selection?

Comment: Have you tried to get the value of the field input HTML tag? I am pretty certain it returns the file name (or an object containing it).

Comment: That would probably require some js code, right? I have no idea how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it using the method described [here](https://www.abeautifulsite.net/whipping-file-inputs-into-shape-with-bootstrap-3) .